# How can I do something in Rails only if the response to the client succeeds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to have an action that formats a response, responds to the client, and then commits something to a database only if the client managed to receive the response. From what I understand of after_filters, they only intercept the response before it is sent to the client. Any ideas?

Comment: This is extremely silly. Why would you expect the client to request something, and then ignore your response? You don't get any kind of confirmation from the client, nor should you look for one. At best, you can include some JavaScript in your response to trigger a *second* request, and on *that* request write to the database. You shouldn't do this though.

Comment: To elaborate, I am referring to connection-level failure. I want to transact only if my HTTP 200 response fails to go through. There are numerous reasons someone might want to do this, in mine, I am serving an API endpoint, and do not wish to do anything that my caller cannot confirm that I did.

Comment: Leave it to TCP/IP. You're operating at a layer where, if the client ignores your response, it's not your problem.

Comment: While I would love to simply ignore dropped connections, there is money involved. Are you saying Rails has no way of indicating whether its responses are received? I can see this being true if Rails is being reverse-proxied by nginx, but I am not sure if this is true in general.

Comment: I sincerely doubt it is possible to tell whether the client received the response, as this is *far* outside the realm of Rails' responsibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no reliable way of confirming that the client received a message at the application level other than instructing the client to send an additional request, e.g. with javascript.

Instead of relying on the client to receive your 200 message, I would put a list of successful transactions with the API somewhere else in the API so that the client can proactively visit that list to verify that transactions went through.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a reasonable thing to do, despite the other commentator.  I do agree with his approach to write javascript which sends an acknowledgement.

I wouldn't leave a transaction open that long, so I recommend saving the data with a tentative flag, and then when you get the acknowledgement, mark the data as acknowledged.